# import stl into moveit

Tags: ros, moveit, stl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

All,

I would like to add a custom scene to moveit using my own stl file. Is there any documentation on how that works? The only information I found is [this](http://moveit.ros.org/wiki/index.php/Groovy/Environment_Representation/Rviz#Adding_Mesh_Objects_to_the_Planning_Scene).
It works as described but when I try to import a stl file I exported from Solidworks, I receive an error saying: unable to import scene

```
Assimp reports no scene in file:///home/asdf.stl
```

I looked at the box.stl and it says it was exported using blender but I would like to use Solidworks :(

Any help is appreciated.

Kai

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/61094/import-stl-into-moveit/) by [kalectro](https://answers.ros.org/users/3904/kalectro/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1554 on 2013-04-18

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had the same problem when I saved my CAD model as a .stl file in binary format.
It worked for me to save my CAD model as a .stl file in aschii format in SolidWorks.

---

Originally posted by [mortenpj](https://answers.ros.org/users/7376/mortenpj/) with karma: 70 on 2014-02-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-02-10**:
@mortenpj: binary STLs work fine, but SolidWorks places the string 'solid' in the STL header (first 80 bytes). Assimp doesn't like this, as it assumes headers with 'solid' in them are followed by ascii STLs. Replace the 'solid' string with 'dilos' for instance and everything should work.